# NIO Files.getLastModifiedTime() returns incorrect value for some ZIP-entries

Tags: java, nio

When I print the modified date of *some* files inside *some* ZIP-files, the `Files.getLastModifiedTime()` appears to return the current time. I've checked the date of the file in question with custom file managers, and they report the correct date.

I don't have an example zip-file for now, but this happens with relatively many zip-files.

Here's the code:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/example.zip");
try (FileSystems jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap())) {
    Path resourcePath = jarFS.getPath("testfile.foo"); 
    FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(resourcePath);
    System.out.println(fileTime);
}
```

Anyone have ideas why the correct last-modified time is not always reported?

Comment: What happens if you use the ZipFile API instead of the FileSystems API to get this info? I've run into quite a few bugs with the FileSystems API anytime you are using a file system that isn't the default one. Before reaching for that heavy stick of  'this is a bug in the VM', though, checking out what happens when using ZipFile seems like a valuable bit of research :)

Comment: OK, it appears that this actually happens only for directories, not for regular files. And, for these exact folders that lack the last-modified time, ZipFile does not list directory entries at all: I just learnt that actual directories do not exist inside zip-files, but are _sometimes_ represented as empty files. My guess is, that the external file manager (Total Commander) that displayed the last-modified time, simply scouts the contents of the folder and displays the last modified date of the latest file. By the way, "src.zip" file inside JDK distribution is full of such folders.

Comment: Sounds like you could self-answer the question.